# How can I focus a button after its been enabled in react js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to react js and I'm trying to focus on a button after completing all input fields, after that, I'm enabling that button programmatically but I'm not able to focus on it. I'm also using autoFocus in its implementation

```
return (
            <div style={{ marginTop: '10%', marginLeft: '25%', backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, rgba(153,102,255,1), rgba(153,102,255,0.5))', color: '#f3f5f7', height: 'fit-content%', width: '50%', paddingBlockStart: '50px', position: 'fixed' }}>

                <form align="center"  >
                    <h1 align="center"> Login</h1><br /><br />

                    <Grid container direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center" spacing={4} >
                        <Grid item >
                            <TextField input type="number" placeholder={this.props.intl.formatMessage(messages.PlaceHolder)} id="mobileNo" variant="outlined" size="small" required style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', width: '300px', borderRadius: '5px', border: '1px solid' }} onInput={(e) => { e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value)).toString().slice(0, 11) }} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item >
                            <MyButton disabled={this.state.validate} variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={() => this.clickValidate()}> {this.props.intl.formatMessage(messages.ValidateButton)} </MyButton>
                            <ToastContainer />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <br /><br />
                    <Grid container direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center" spacing={4} >
                        <Grid item >
                            <ValidationTextField type="number" onInput={this.restrictAlphabets} min={0} required id="otp_1" variant="outlined" size="small" onChange={this.handleChange} inputProps={{ maxLength: 1, size: 1 }} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', width: '50px', borderRadius: '5px', border: '1px solid' }} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item >
                            <ValidationTextField type="number" onInput={this.restrictAlphabets} min={0} required id="otp_2" variant="outlined" size="small" onChange={this.handleChange} inputProps={{ maxLength: 1, size: 1 }} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', width: '50px', borderRadius: '5px', border: '1px solid' }} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item >
                            <ValidationTextField type="number" onInput={this.restrictAlphabets} min={0} required id="otp_3" variant="outlined" size="small" onChange={this.handleChange} inputProps={{ maxLength: 1, size: 1 }} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', width: '50px', borderRadius: '5px', border: '1px solid' }} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item >
                            <ValidationTextField type="number" onInput={this.restrictAlphabets} min={0} required id="otp_4" variant="outlined" size="small" onChange={this.handleChange} inputProps={{ maxLength: 1, size: 1 }} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', width: '50px', borderRadius: '5px', border: '1px solid' }} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item >
                            <ValidationTextField type="number" onInput={this.restrictAlphabets} min={0} required id="otp_5" variant="outlined" size="small" onChange={this.handleChange} inputProps={{ maxLength: 1, size: 1 }} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', width: '50px', borderRadius: '5px', border: '1px solid' }} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item >
                            <ValidationTextField type="number" onInput={this.restrictAlphabets} min={0} required id="otp_6" variant="outlined" size="small" onChange={this.handleChange} inputProps={{ maxLength: 1, size: 1 }} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', width: '50px', borderRadius: '5px', border: '1px solid' }} />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <br /><br /><br />

                    <MyButton id="login" variant="outlined" aria-disabled={this.state.login} color="primary" onClick={this.handelLogin}> {this.props.intl.formatMessage(messages.Login)} </MyButton>
                    <br /><br /><br />
                    <Link style={{ color: 'white' }} onClick={this.handelResendOtp}> {this.props.intl.formatMessage(messages.ResendOtp)} </Link>
                    <br /><br /><br />

                </form>

                <div id="regAlert" style={this.state.unregistered ? {} : { display: 'none' }}>
                    <Alert severity="info"><h3>You are not registered with us, kindly visit www.agoraservices.us for registration!</h3></Alert >
                </div>

            </div>
```

above are some sample code and I'm trying to focus on the Login button

Comment: The react docs on [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) are likely a good place to start; their example is even programmatically setting focus on an element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ref provided by react to refer to any HTML element, later you can access it using it's current property.

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-neumann-07wdi?file=/src/App.js

```
function App() {
  const mybtnRef = useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    mybtnRef.current.focus();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button ref={mybtnRef} onClick={()=>console.log("hello")}>Click here</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What if i also want to disable it if input fields are empty ? and if not empty then enable that button and also focus on it at a same time ?

Comment: All of these can be done using this .You have to have a eventHandler on input box, then  in thevenethandler, check their value, whether it's empty or not. Based upon that call mybtn.current.focus.

Comment: I also want to disable it for sometime

Comment: Yeah just have  mybtnRef.current.disabled=true;

Comment: Can you please mark this as answer, others may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- you can take reference from my code of focus or changing background color as well--> 
<html>

<head>
  
    <style>
        td {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        
        td:first-child {
            width: 300px;
        }
    </style>  </head>

<body>
  
  <div id="message">some text here</div>
   
 <div>
        <input type="text" id="addFriend">
        <input type="button" id="addNew" value="Add Friend"> </div>
    <div class="output"></div>
    <script>
<!-- array calling for listout -->
        var myArray = ["Laurence", "Mike", "John", "Larry", "Kim", "Joanne", "Lisa", "Janet", "Jane"];
        window.onload = build;
        document.getElementById('addNew').addEventListener('click', addN, false);

        function addN() {
            var a = document.getElementById('addFriend').value;
            myArray.push(a);
            build();
        }

        function build() {
            var html = "<h1>Click Table</h1><table>";
            for (var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
                html += '<tr id="id' + x + '" data-row="' + x + '"><td>' + myArray[x] + '</td><td><a href="#" data-action="delete">Del</a></td><td><a href="#" data-action="edit">Edit</a></td></tr>';
            }
            document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = html;
            var dad = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action="delete"]');
            for (var x = 0; x < dad.length; x++) {
                dad[x].addEventListener('click', function () {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var iValue = this.closest('[data-row]').getAttribute('data-row');
                    var r = myArray.splice(iValue, 1);
                    build();
                    console.log(r);
                })
            }
            var dae = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action="edit"]');
            for (var x = 0; x < dae.length; x++) {
                dae[x].addEventListener('click', function () {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var row = this.closest('[data-row]');
                    var rid = row.getAttribute('data-row');
                    row.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
                    var td = row.firstElementChild;
                    var input = document.createElement('input');
                    input.type = "text";
                    input.value = td.innerText;
                    td.innerHTML = "";
                    td.appendChild(input);
                    input.focus();
                    input.onblur = function () {
                        td.removeChild(input);
                        td.innerHTML = input.value;
                        myArray[rid] = input.value;
                        row.style.backgroundColor = "White"
                    }
                })
            }
            console.log(dad);
        }
    </script> </body>

</html>
```